# Maximum values in matrix

Tags: algorithm, optimization

So here is an interesting problem in C#. I'm looking for a better way of solving it:

> Given a matrix M (not necesarily square) of matches, find the best matching elements. Element i matches elem j by value M(i,j). M(i,j) != M(j,i).
>
> Since #rows != #columns, find the best min(#rows,#columns) matching pairs (i,j).

Basically the problem is to pick the maximum from each row/column such that no row/column is picked twice.

Example:

```
     1  2  3 
  +---------
a | 10  3  1
b | 12  99 2
c | 20  5  3
d |  5  7  4
```

The maximum value in this matrix is 99 so the best match is (b,2). For the next selection we cannot use anymore row b and column 2. Is like cutting them

```
     1  2  3  or, if you prefer,       1   3
  +---------  a smaller matrix:      +------
a | 10 ||  1                       a | 10  1
b | ===++===                       c | 20  3
c | 20 ||  3                       d | 5   4
d |  5 ||  4
```

The max is now 20 and the match is (c, 1). The remaining matrix has only one column.
After another pick we'll get the match (d, 3) with match = 4

In the end "a" has no match.

My current implementation uses 2 array to store the already matched rows/columns and for each match goes through the entire matrix, picking the first maximum that belongs to row/col not match.

PS: in case of value multiple matches having the same value, just pick one of them
PS2: The array is stored as `int [,]`

How would you approach this problem in a more optimal/beautiful way?

Comment: Keep column/rows indices that are left as opposed to keeping those that are eliminated?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to maximise the sum of the cells chosen, such that exactly one cell is picked from each row and from each column, then this is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem. If your matrix is not square, you can make it square by adding rows or columns to them, with values in the new cells which mean that they won't be picked unless there is no other way to fill out the solution.

(If you are not maximising the sum, you need to say what function of the values chosen you are maximising - is (1,3) better than (2,2)?. Otherwise you are into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization, which is possible, but more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

You could first sort all of the entries of the matrix in descending order, and then process the sorted list. Whenever you see an entry that isn't in an already-picked row/col, it means that entry should be picked, so you mark the corresponding row/column and continue further down the list until either all rows or all columns have been picked.